# Generate valid English sentence structure for a given word length

Tags: javascript, algorithm, nlp, nlg

Does a library exist, preferably JavaScript (by no means a hard requirement), that will output an English sentence structure for a given length?

For example:

```
> sentenceGenerator({ length: 4 })
< DETERMINER NOUN VERB NOUN

> sentenceGenerator({ length: 8 })
< PRONOUN NOUN VERB NOUN CONJUNCTION PRONOUN VERB ADVERB
```

The reason I'm looking for this is because I'd like to generate sentences using my own wordlist. Existing NLG libraries don't fit my needs since I'd like to specify a letter for each index (e.g. mnemonics).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659838/simple-random-english-sentence-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working using markov chains and a part-of-speech tagging library.

`markov-strings` and `pos` respectively on npm.